# Sending information from one EV3 brick to another EV3 brick

Tags: ev3, robotc

I am working on a project using RobotC and multiple EV3 bricks to participate in a robotics challenge. I am wondering if it is possible to send sensor values from one brick to another through either bluetooth or USB? All of this is through code, and not using the graphical interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, RobotC does not support Bluetooth messaging[[1](http://www.robotc.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=33285&sid=1c25096d522355f42ed89227acc6591e)] or USB daisy chaining[[2](http://www.robotc.net/download/lego/)] LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 programmable bricks.

Comment: It seems to be working for two NXT bricks